# Python Tkinter Getting error every time I delete unused parameter form __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter

I've been making an Object-Oriented Tkinter App, and since I don't want to write everything for class definition every time I copied it from my other class. But I forgot one unused parameter in `__init__`, now I'm cleaning my code and I noticed that, so I tried to remove that parameter, but when I do it, I get an error.

My code:

**main.py**

```
from app import App
import tkinter as tk

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Title")
    # root.minsize(800, 600)
    root.minsize(800, 600)
    App(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

**app.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from registered import Registered



class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.note2 = Registered(self, self.parent)

       
        self.notebook.add(self.note2, text='Register')
        self.notebook.pack()
```

**registered.py**

```
import tkinter as tk

class Registered(tk.Frame):
    """Form frame """
    def __init__(self, parent, test, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        print("hey")
```

This works fine, but when i remove test from `__init__` like this:

```
class Registered(tk.Frame):
    """Form frame """
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        print("hey")
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kryst/PycharmProjects/covidForm/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    App(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
  File "C:\Users\kryst\PycharmProjects\covidForm\app.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.note2 = Registered(self, self.parent)
  File "C:\Users\kryst\PycharmProjects\covidForm\registered.py", line 12, in __init__
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kryst\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3119, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "C:\Users\kryst\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2567, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-menu"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is all my code that is runned, I use PyCharm Professional, but the error shows even in the terminal, my python version is 3.9, but I tried 3.8 and i still got the error.

Does anyone know why I keep getting this error? I really can't find the reason.

Comment: I can't tell for sure, since you didn't supply a [mcve], but you probably just need to remove that unneeded parameter in each place where an instance of `Registered` gets created.

Comment: I think that @jasonharper is correct and somewhere you call `Registered` with a `menu` parameter.

Comment: I updated the question with one more file, and it's the only file where I call Registered class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with passing `self.parent` to that class. Removing it solved everything.

Comment: To explain what happened: the parameter wasn't actually unused. Where you had `self.note2 = Registered(self, self.parent)`, `self` became the `parent` for `Registered.__init__`, and `self.parent` became the `test`. By removing the `test` parameter from the method declaration but not from the call, that value (`self.parent`, i.e. the `tk.Tk` instance that is the `parent` of the `App`) ended up in the `*args` list, which was then forwarded to `tk.Frame.__init__`, where it caused a problem.